# Fixar div na parte de baixo da página

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Gostaria de saber como deixo uma `<div>` fixa na parte de baixo da página, tipo eu fiz ela ficar em baixo com `margin-top`, mas só que no `Firefox` e uma coisa quando abro no `Chrome` a `<div>` não fica no rodapé.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesta oura resposta que dei: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72075/como-fixar-um-rodap%C3%A9-no-bottom-mesmo-com-muito-conte%C3%BAdo/72097#72097

Comment: na verdade eu queria que desse um auto poscionamento. por que quando abro no firefox e uma coisa mais quando abro no chrome ele não fica em baixo na tela

Comment: eu quero ver se deixo a div fixa na parte de baixo da tela

Comment: O que queres é um rodapé que fique sempre no fundo ([sticky footer](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/))?

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu seu problema? Não se esqueça de dar um voto positivo e escolher a resposta correta.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente uma **solução testada nos 3 browsers principais** (`Chrome`, `FireFox` e `Internet Explorer 8+`)

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
        html, body,#wrap {margin:0; padding:0;  height:100%;}
        #wrap {display:table;width:100%}
        /* if ie7 support is needed then set height of #wrap and header and footer to auto in CC's and just let it have a normal layout (or: *+html #wrap{height:auto})*/
        .content { background:#ccc; }
        header {    background:#999;    color:#fff; text-align:center;  padding:10px 0}
        header, .footer, main { display:block}/* ie7 and under*/
        header, .footer, main { display:table-row }
        /* height 1px on the header and footer is the sticky footer technique */
        header, .footer{height:1px}
        h1{padding:10px;margin:0;}
        .footer {background:#999;   color:#fff; text-align:center;}
        .footer p { margin:0;   padding:10px}

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- html5 shiv for IE8 and under -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- If you aren't using jquery you can use the body element instead (body{width:100%;display:table;height:100%})of the #wrap div as jquery has a bug (
    http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7261) in webkit when the body is display:table. -->

    <div id="wrap">
        <header><h1>Cabeçalho (Funciona no FF, IE 8+, Chrome)</h1></header>

        <main class="content">

            Conteúdo aqui

        </main>

        <footer class="footer"><p>Rodapé</p></footer>
    </div>
```

**Completo**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Incluindo JS</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body,#wrap {margin:0; padding:0;  height:100%;}
        #wrap {display:table;width:100%}
        /* if ie7 support is needed then set height of #wrap and header and footer to auto in CC's and just let it have a normal layout (or: *+html #wrap{height:auto})*/
        .content { background:#ccc; }
        header {    background:#999;    color:#fff; text-align:center;  padding:10px 0}
        header, .footer, main { display:block}/* ie7 and under*/
        header, .footer, main { display:table-row }
        /* height 1px on the header and footer is the sticky footer technique */
        header, .footer{height:1px}
        h1{padding:10px;margin:0;}
        .footer {background:#999;   color:#fff; text-align:center;}
        .footer p { margin:0;   padding:10px}

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- html5 shiv for IE8 and under -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- If you aren't using jquery you can use the body element instead (body{width:100%;display:table;height:100%})of the #wrap div as jquery has a bug (
    http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7261) in webkit when the body is display:table. -->

    <div id="wrap">
        <header><h1>Cabeçalho (Funciona no FF, IE 8+, Chrome)</h1></header>

        <main class="content">

            Conteúdo aqui

        </main>

        <footer class="footer"><p>Rodapé</p></footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/ahy5vuug/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Podes utilizar o seguinte código para fixar em todos os browser da mesma forma.

Desta maneira utilizando o "**position: fixed;**"

```
.footer {
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

geralmente o pessoal fixa ele usando posicionamento absoluto, dessa maneira:

```
.footer {
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use uma combinação de `position:absolute` no elemento que deseja fixar abaixo.

```
footer {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #BBBDBF;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Com um `position:relative` no body do documento:

```
body{
    position:relative
}
```